# How to solve "Insert or Update on a table violates fk not null constraint" when using Entity Framework core

Tags: entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I have two entities having double 1:N relationships to each other.

```
Worker:1 - n:Team : Management aspect relationship.
Team:1 - n:Worker : Affiliation aspect one.
```

Psuedo code

```
class Base { Guid Id; }

class Team : Base
{
    Worker? Manager;
    Worker[] Members; 
}

class Worker : Base
{
    Team? Team;
    Team[] Managings;
}
```

```
// IEntityTypeConfiguration<Team>.Configure

// Management relationship
builder.HasOne( x => x.Manager)
    .WithMany( x => Managings)
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

// Affliation relationship
builder.HasMany( x => x.Members)
    .WithOne(x=>x.Team)
    .IsRequied(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

Each DB table successfully has a foreign key to their principal.

The below code generated the titled error:

```
dbcontext.Workers.Add( new Worker(){ Team = new Team(), } );
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

How can I solve the FK error?